# WebdriverIO 7: chromedriver is opened with small reoslution

Tags: webdriver-io

I am migrating from webdriverIO6 to 7. These are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.12.13",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/register": "^7.12.13",
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^7.0.0",
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.0.5",
    "@wdio/config": "^7.0.4",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^7.0.6",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.0.5",
    "@wdio/sauce-service": "^7.0.5",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^7.0.4",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.0.4",
    "@wdio/static-server-service": "^7.0.4",
    "@wdio/sync": "^7.0.5",
    "chromedriver": "^88.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-wdio": "^7.0.0",
    "http-server": "^0.12.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^6.0.4",
    "webdriverio": "^7.0.5"
  }
```

I am able to execute my tests using the sauce service controlling the resolution.

My problem is that executing the tests on my local with the chromedriver, the browser is opened but the resolution is too small and it is not filling the window (see attached image). This causes a failure in my tests.

My wdio configuration is:

```
capabilities: [
        {
          browserName: 'chrome',
}]
```

When I was using webdriverIO 6 my configuration was the same and the problem was not reproduced, the chromedriver resolution was maximized to the browser. These were my dependencies with webdriverIO6:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.12.10",
    "@babel/core": "7.12.10",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.12.11",
    "@babel/register": "7.12.10",
    "@types/cucumber": "^6.0.1",
    "@wdio/cli": "^6.12.0",
    "@wdio/config": "^6.11.0",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^6.11.1",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^6.12.0",
    "@wdio/sauce-service": "^6.12.1",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^6.11.0",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^6.11.0",
    "@wdio/static-server-service": "^6.10.10",
    "@wdio/sync": "^6.11.0",
    "chromedriver": "^87.0.5",
    "eslint": "^7.17.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-wdio": "^6.6.0",
    "http-server": "^0.12.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^6.0.4",
    "webdriverio": "^6.12.0"
  }
```

I have checked the webdriverIO7 release note but I can't see any related change. In addition, I have checked the different packages but I can't see any solution.

Has anyone reproduced the same issue? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

[chromedriver is shown with small resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcOEV.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded the packet "@wdio/local-runner" to the previous major version "^6.12.0" and the issue is not reproduced. So I don't know if there is an issue in the latest release or the problem is in my dependencies configuration